# Ignore "missing file doc comment" rule from Wordpress Coding Standards

Tags: wordpress

I would like to ignore the rule in the Wordpress Coding Standards that generate the error "missing file doc comment" in VSCode. I have been unable to find the exact rule and I am unsure how to ignore it if I were to find it. There are other threads about ignoring rules, but since I can't find the specific rule name I haven't had any luck by searching SO or google or even asking gpt3.5.

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

```
<rule ref="WordPress">
    <exclude name="Squiz.Commenting.FileComment"/>
</rule>
```